# How do I connect a GitHub organization to Microsoft Teams?

Tags: github, microsoft-teams

When I use the [GitHub Bot](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/github-code-better-together-with-github-and-microsoft-teams/ba-p/659444), it only displays GitHub repositories that I own. It does not include repositories, issues, and pull requests for an organization that I contribute to.

[image]

How do I connect a GitHub organization to Microsoft Teams so that I can list and post details of issues and pull requests I created in my organization?

Comment: Thank you for sharing the feedback. Currently the GitHub bot don't have features to support for organization related  repositories, issues and pull request that we contribute. We have added this in feature backlog and will discuss with feature team regarding prioritization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is currently not available. The GitHub Microsoft Teams integration creators have added it to their feature backlog.

> Thank you for sharing the feedback. Currently the GitHub bot don't have features to support for organization related repositories, issues and pull request that we contribute. We have added this in feature backlog and will discuss with feature team regarding prioritization. — [Subhasish-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12318748/subhasish-msft)